# Typescript compiler failing with strange error

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors, gulp, browserify

I'm getting the following error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
TypeScript error: node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/compiler.d.ts(32,22): Error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

My gulpfile https://github.com/rtaycher/2048-Clone/blob/master/gulpfile.js

I also have a declaration file global.d.ts:

```
interface Array<T> {
    includes(searchElement: T) : boolean;
}
```

Some googling indicates that declaration files might cause issues.

Comment: what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: tsc Version 1.8.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error TS1005: '=' expected

The error is two fold.

- an old version of the definition file e.g. this verion has `readonly`  https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript/blob/3645edb57278a22e08e6ae9780dc09b8ae68003e/release/compiler.d.ts#L32
- an old version of the compiler that doesn't support new keywords (like `readonly`).

## Personal opinion

Please use TypeScript nightlies otherwise it will always be an uphill / confusing battle.